# Erlang generate random binary

Tags: random, erlang

What is the most efficient way to generate a random binary object given a number of bits? I understand that the `crypto:rand_bytes` function would be an option, but the bit count must not necessarily be a multiply of 8.

Comment: If it's random then you can always cut the unnecessary bits. Won't make much difference.

Comment: @Amiramix how would I achieve that exactly please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rand_bits(Bits) ->
    Bytes = (Bits + 7) div 8,
    <<Result:Bits/bits, _/bits>> = crypto:rand_bytes(Bytes),
    Result.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that you will be able to do it is:

```
<<(rand:uniform(MaxNum)):(rand:uniform(MaxBits))>>
```

Or same way if you wish to use the crypto module:

```
<<(crypto:rand_uniform(MinNum, MaxNum)):(crypto:rand_uniform(MinBits, MaxBits))>>
```